# Unable to open xls file in Openoffice calc

Tags: openoffice.org, xls

I am unable to open an xls file in Open Office 4.1.1. The same file is getting opened in Microsoft Excel. But in this, when I open the file, it is showing blank.

Comment: Try LibreOffice which is the fork of OpenOffice supported by Ubuntu and Debian Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your immd reply,I am facing this issue in client place, and already our appln is in LIVE, hence kindly provide solution in openoffice itself.

Comment: Yes, Also would like to brief more so that it might be clear for you to help me. Excel file will be generated dynamically and saved in server where the client/customer will pick this excel (.xls) and opens it in ods but sees blank. Then I clicked saveas in open office it shows extension by default .xml, I renamed to xls then the data is shown.

Comment: Wouldn't automatically rename the files be an option (or better: edit the generating process) or am I missing something?

Comment: Renaming the file in my machine and then open this file from client machine it works BUT if i rename the same file in client machine it is not working (i.e. data showing blank while opening in openoffice).

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Use LibreOffice instead.
2. Convert it to ODS using Microsoft Office.
3. Convert it to ODS by uploading and converting it to Google Sheets format first.
4. Convert it to ODS by using a website such as [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com) ([source](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=67299)).

Comment: I cannot do this as you said, kindly see my comment above.

Comment: I don't know sorry, what you're trying to do is WAAAY beyond my knowledge :(